# Как, используя wpf mvvm, нарисовать таблицу

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Зашла в тупик.
Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки нарисовать такую таблицу:
[image: таблица]

Кол-во x-переменных и чисел генерируется в коде, но после отрисовки меняться не будет, но будут меняться между собой местами, так же динамически будут меняться значения.

Хотя бы намек на инструмент/алгоритм был бы полезен

Comment: так а в чем конкретно проблема то?

Comment: Что использовать, что бы отрисовать это и изменять в дальнейшем

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/ удачи

Comment: для отрисовки таблиц обычно используется [DataGrid](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/5.14.php)